# Twitter application OAuth2 more than one callback URL

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0

For the purpose of my application I need to have a second Twitter OAuth2 callback URL. I tried to separate the URLs with `,`, `:` and `;`, but none of these worked.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is not possible in an oauth-2.0 context. You can have one and only one redirect uri per authorization request